# How to break a loop when inputting unspecified raw_input?

Tags: python, while-loop, raw-input

I want to write an interface using a while loop and raw_input.

My code looks like this:

```
while True:
    n = raw_input("'p' = pause, 'u' = unpause, 'p' = play 's' = stop, 'q' = quit)
    if n.strip() == 'p':
        mp3.pause()
    if n.strip() == 'u':
        mp3.unpause()
    if n.strip() == 'p':
        mp3.play()
    if n.strip() == 's':
        mp3.stop()
    if n.strip() == 'q':
        break
```

But I want it to break if I input anything that isn't specified in the raw_input.

```
    if not raw_input:
        break
```

Returns and IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.

```
        if not raw_input:
            break
```

Does not return any error but doesn't work as I want it to. As far as I know, it does nothing at all.

Also, if there's a cleaner way to write my loop, I love to hear it.

Comment: You have syntactical problems, use an editor that displays whitespace since they are significant in python.

Comment: When you say 'anything that isn't specified in the raw_input' what do you mean?

Comment: 'p' = pause and 'p' = play ... Why?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry, I edited the commands to add all the options that my actual script contains but I forgot to change the input.
In my script it's "'s' = Suspend".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an indent error because you do not have a closing double quote.

```
n = raw_input("'p' = pause, 'u' = unpause, 'p' = play 's' = stop, 'q' = quit")
```

If you want to have the while look break if there is any other value then put all of your conditions into elif statements, and an all includisve else at the end. Also I just put lower and strip onto the end of the raw_input statement.

```
while True:
    n = raw_input("'p' = pause, 'u' = unpause, 'pl' = play 's' = stop, 'q' = quit").strip().lower()
    if n == 'p':
        mp3.pause()
    elif n == 'u':
        mp3.unpause()
    elif n == 'pl':
        mp3.play()
    elif n == 's':
        mp3.stop()
    elif n == 'q':
        break
    else:
        break
```

You could also put all of the valid answer options into a dictionary, but it looks like you should start with the simple solution to understand the flow. Also you used a p for both play and pause. You will want to use a unique value to differentiate so I added 'pl' for play.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere. And for the input, I had different values assigned in my script, but when I was writing this question, I was initially going to use only the pause and unpause parts. I'm still learning python (less than a week in) and so I haven't quite gotten the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a dict to hold all function is a cleaner way.

```
func_dict = {
    'pause': mp3.pause,
    'unpause': mp3.unpause,
    'play': mp3.play,
    'stop': mp3.stop,
}

while True:
    n = raw_input("'p' = pause, 'u' = unpause, 'p' = play 's' = stop, 'q' = quit")
    if n.strip() in func_dict.keys():
        func_dict[n]()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Or perhaps, `else: print('unknown command: {}'.format(n.strip()))`

Comment: Ahh. I was reading about dictionaries but I couldn't figure out how to implement them into my specific script. This is great, thank you!